# How can I filter duplicate documents in couchdb from within the map function itself

Tags: couchdb

**SITUATION**
I have a set of documents called "touches" that point to a set of documents called "consumers" in a many to one type of relationship

```
_id     : 0
type    : touch
consumer: 1 //three touches pointing to one consumer
agent   : bill

_id     : 1
type    : touch
consumer: 1 //three touches pointing to one consumer
agent   : ted

_id     : 2
type    : touch
consumer: 1 //three touches pointing to one consumer
agent   : ted
```

I'm actually trying to load the consumer information only for consumers that ted has "touched" so my query looks like this

```
 get_touches?agent=ted&include_docs=true
```

**PROBLEM**
The problem is that I don't want to show the same consumer info more than once. So, inspired by this SO answer [Replace multiple joins in SQL with CouchDB views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526006/replace-multiple-joins-in-sql-with-couchdb-views#answer-10663103) I wrote the following map function to filter the results.

```
"map": "var ids = []; 
        function(doc){
            if(doc.type === \"touch\" && !ids.contains(doc.consumer)){         
               ids.push(doc.consumer); 
               emit(doc._id, {\"_id\": doc.consumer});
            }
        }"
```

And it only returns an empty set. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or even if this actually works.

**MORE INFO**
Many agents can touch a single consumer many times each so storing touching agent or touches in the consumer document is not a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot access more than one document at any one time in the map function. The examples pushing data into an array outside the map function won't store data across documents.

It would be a simple reduce function though that merely takes the first document for any given key.

The alternative - could be to store the data by user, ie. updating documents with a key that is the consumer and just adding to an list that stores all the touches. Obviously this has disadvantages if you want to access the data by eg. the agent.